Is there a way to make shopify checkout work if the store is being opened in iframe? (Checkout Extensibility issue)
Recently we have started opening our shopify stores in iframe. The first store is working pretty fine in iframe, all transactions are happening as expected.
The second store is facing issue where as soon as I click on 'checkout', the whole site breaks down saying 'xyz.com refused to connect'.
Now I've already contacted shopify support team regarding the same, the reason they gave behind this issue is that the first store is still using the old checkout.liquid file because of which its working without an error. However the second store is using checkout extensibility due to which its not working. I believe all the latest stores are automatically upgraded to checkout extensibility. They have not provided any way around for this issue which is a big problem for me as of now.
Is there a way around of this issue? Where the store can still be opened in iframe and the user can complete the journey of payment and everything.
PFA screenshots for reference:
Whenever I click on checkout:

Checkout extensibility upgraded:

Taking into account that our first store started working in iframe, we were pretty hopeful regarding the second store too, until we encountered this issue. Earlier we thought this might be something related Content-Security-Policy header, as thats when this refused to connect error normally comes up. But overall this came out to be particularly related to shopify checkout issue.
